# Android ViewPagerIndicator Tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, foursquare, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator

I got stuck with Jake Wharton `ViewPagerIndicator`.

The problem is that when I try to make a `Tab indicator` - the result I'm getting is extremely different from what I need and I can't get to style it or make it behave as it should.

So, what I ask for is two things:
1) Am I right when I say that `TabIndicator` is Foursquare-like `ViewPagerIndicator`? (when all tabs are shown on screen)
2) Can anyone provide me links to some tutorials or samples of using this type of `ViewPagerIndicator`, cause samples from JWs' site don't want to get working.

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moskis is right on about `ViewPagerIndicator`.  Installing that APK helped me a lot when I first started working with it and it is a great library.

However, to answer the first part of your question and what I think you are asking in general, I think `ViewPagerIndicator` isn't what you need to solve this specific problem. Foursquare's tabs at the top are the standard Android tabs as shown in http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html.

Standard Android tabs are implemented using a `TabHost` and `TabWidget`. There is an official tutorial about creating a tabbed interface at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/tabs.html

Foursquare achieves a custom look by providing state-list drawables for the tabs and you will probably want to provide your own to get the style that you want for your app.

Note that I don't have access to the Foursquare implementation, but am going off of what I observe whiel using the app.  However, I have implemented a tabbed interface for Android in past projects.

Answer (score 2):

Jake Wharton provides a lot of examples. Have you checked it?
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

And you can take a preview installing this apk:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample&hl=es